# Date and time difference display 30min as 5

Tags: php

I have tried to compare two dates and time using this php code

```
<?php $A = "2013-01-10 10:30:00";
    $B = "2013-01-10 12:00:00";
    echo str_replace('-','',(strtotime($A) - strtotime($B))/(60*60));
    ?>
```

code working fine but its display 30 min as 5 so i not able to checks this with db values any idea to fix this one

Comment: why you user str_replace function in this code?????

Comment: What do you need to know ?

Comment: 1.5 to 1.30 thats all

Comment: @SmartKaliDass 1.5 -> 1.30 Or the other way around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtotime()` alone can calculate the difference. There is no need to use `str_replace()`. Try with -

```
echo (strtotime($B) - strtotime($A))/60;
```

Will return the difference in `minutes` ie. `90`. If you want it like `1.30` then have to do some basic calculations. -

```
$mins = (strtotime($B) - strtotime($A))/60;
if ($mins > 60) {
    echo ((int)($mins/60)).'.'.($mins%60);
} else {
    echo $mins;
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @PedroLobito Not Working? It was returning the difference in hours and for `-` `$B > $A`.

Comment: @SmartKaliDass I think the code is working and returning the correct result - `90` minutes.

Comment: ya thats code working fine but i need minutes as normal format like 90 mins  as 1.30 mins

Comment: my code already fine @PedroLobito needs some out put change only

Comment: @SmartKaliDass Updated the answer. Hope will solve the problem.

Comment: display 1.30min as 1.5 this is my code doing i need to show 1.5 as 1.30min

Comment: thank for answer but if you have little bit of time update this answer with predefined php  functions

Comment: @SmartKaliDass if there any then i think you will get those.

Comment: but without str_replace() this code not work so remove that from answer thats helps other to explore correct answer if have doubts try with this                $A = "2013-01-10 12:00:00";
$B = "2013-01-10 11:50:00";

Answer (score 1):

I've updated my answer based on your comment, to get the difference in hours (ie: 1.5) you need:

```
 $A = "2013-01-10 10:30:00";
 $B = "2013-01-10 12:00:00";

echo (strtotime($B) - strtotime($A))/3600;
```

---

Output:

```
1.5
```

---

demo:
http://ideone.com/ovEr0F

Comment: this you can get by simply echo (strtotime($A) - strtotime($B))/60;